# max no of times a particular character in a string in knuth morris pratt algorithm comes into comparison with the string?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, knuth-morris-pratt

Let

```
T:String
P:pattern
```

what is the max no of times a particular character in a string(T) in knuth morris pratt algorithm comes into comparison with the pattern(P) ?

Answer (score 0):

`|P|`. Here is an example:

`P = aaa...a(n times)`
`T = aaa...a(n times)b`

When we reach `b`, the current value of the counter is `n`. Each comparison decreases it by exactly one. Thus, it makes exactly `n` iterations until it reaches zero.

Why is it an upper bound?

It is obvious that the number of comparisons is at most `|P|`(each comparison decreases the value of prefix function by at least one and it can never exceed `|P|`).

Comment: what if the string P=abababab and pattern T=abc then don't you think that after the first a every a gets compared 2 times ?